# Printer Xerox Phaser 6000 not working

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, xerox

I've, already download the drivers on xerox website, installed and added the printer in CUPS, but when I try to print something, nothing happens.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 64 bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Driver packagers at xerox did not care to add dependencies. 
On Ubuntu 14 you will need to

```
sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2:i386
```

On old ubuntus, I think package `ia32-libs` will do. 
Restart CUPS daemon afterwards

```
sudo  /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

**UPDATE**
In Unicorn, I had to

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
```

additionally.

**MORE UPDATE**
Ubuntu 16.10. Developer's driver still works, even though it was last updated in 2010. You need to install 2 packages above, reboot cups, set printer and reboot cups again. 
Ubuntu offers preinstalled driver for the printer and it does not work.

Ubuntu 17.10. Still works!No cups rebooting was needed. However, if printer is idle for a minute or two, it turns off its fans. After that, it does not wake up, so I have to reboot it.

Comment: Oh, and this is the same for Xerox 6010 too.

Comment: Great! it worked for my NEC MultiWriter 5600C printer (which is the same driver as Xerox 6000b). I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bits